# Android XML-animations "bind" pivot to a special point

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-alertdialog

I'm writing an Android-app and also I want to use newest Android Material guidelines. So I have an `AlertDialog` and also my own animations in my `anim.xml`. Here my enteranimation of the Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromXScale="0.0"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:fillAfter="false"
       android:startOffset="0"
       android:duration="200"
       android:pivotX="90%"
       android:pivotY="85%"/>

    <translate android:fromYDelta="50%"
           android:toYDelta="0"
           android:startOffset="0"
           android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

This works fine for the portrait mode of the app. But if I switch to landscape mode the animation doesn't work fine anymore.

But instead of the `android:pivotX="90%"` I want the origin-point of my FloatingButton, for instance.

Is there any possibility to "bind" this point to this XML-tags. 
I haven't found anything helpful.

Thanks,

HumpaLumpa007

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to visualise what you are trying to accomplish but you might find [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) helpful. I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like this is only the hard coded version of my XML but perhaps helpful. I'm going to try it asap. Thx